# django-contact-form Site model error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Got the following error while trying to use `django-contact-form`.
I installed it using `pip`, created the templates, setup the email, wrote the `url(r'^contact/', include('contact_form.urls'))` and got the following error:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.locals>.wrapper at 0x00000000048107B8>
  File "C:\Users\Caio\Documents\Projects\JCC\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 113, in __new__
"INSTALLED_APPS." % (module, name)
RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.sites.models.Site doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

Comment: Which django version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you need to add `'django.contrib.sites'` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in your `setting.py` file. Check [Enabling the sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/sites/#enabling-the-sites-framework)